# Why do I get a parse error on '='

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I am currently working 99 haskell problems

I cannot understand why am I getting an error in this function :-

```
repli :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
repli xs n  = concatMap (take n . repeat) xs
```

Comment: are you using the interpreter?

Comment: works fine for me. Do you have an invisible character somewhere?

Comment: `take n . repeat` is the same as `replicate n`. Doesn't really matter here, but it would make it a bit easier to write pointfree, if you're into that.

Comment: you should always include *full error message* in your question, it helps see what's going on. Perhaps there was something about "non-ASCII characters" there? Maybe you copy-pasted it from some web browser window?

Comment: It was a REPL issue. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the REPL, try

```
>>> let repli xs n = concatMap (take n . repeat) xs
```

Writing Haskell in the REPL (ake GHCi) is a bit different to writing it in a file. For one thing, variable bindings and function definitions have to be prefixed with `let` as in

```
>>> let a = 1
>>> let f x = x + a
```

For another, you generally have to enter definitions all on one line. You can separate separate definitions with a semicolon, like this

```
>>> let a = 1; b = 2
```

or you can use multi-line mode, like this

```
>>> :{
>>> let c = 3
>>>     d = 4
>>> :}
```

If you've learnt about monads (have you?) then you can imagine that everything you write in the REPL is part of a `do` block which is of type `IO ()`, with the statements executed as you type them. So in a file you might write

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  name <- getLine
  let greeting = "Hello " ++ name ++ "!"
  putStrLn greeting
```

whereas in the REPL you would write

```
>>> name <- getLine
Chris
>>> let greeting = "Hello " ++ name ++ "!"
>>> putStrLn greeting
Hello Chris!
>>>
```